# SMT Machine Feeders

Tags: surface-mount

I am trying to set up an SMT line. The company that I am interested to buy the pick and place machine from asked me to provide a list regarding feeder quantity. I have included the width of the reel components. The company also mentioned to include how many component types come in trays. Could anyone please let me know how I should find that and if there is anything else I should include in the feeder quantity list before sending it to the company?

Comment: Do you know what your target boards will look like or who designs them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you'd examine each item on your BOM (Bill of Materials) for each product and also investigate whether there may be options - for example you might be buying parts in a tube but T&R would be better.

Trays are usually used for QFP and TQFP packages (photo of JEDEC tray from [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/smt-manufacturing/jedec-trays)).

[image]

There's trade-offs involving how many feeders a given machine can accept and how many (if any) you may decide to load and unload because they are only used infrequently.